# How to change image size using nextjs

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, next.js, bootstrap-cards

I have an image in a bootstrap card using `next/image`. I would like the image to be smaller and not fill the entire top portion of the card. Say about 60% of the original size. I tried to wrap the image in a div container and added some css but did not have any affect on changing the size.

```js
import Image from 'next/image'
import logo from '../public/delta-logo.png'
import { Card, Button } from 'react-bootstrap'
import styles from './landing.module.css'

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'

export default function LandingPage() {
  return (
    <Card style={{ width: '18rem' }}>
      <Image src={logo} alt='Picture of our Logo' />

      <Card.Body className='text-center'>
        <Card.Title>Card Title</Card.Title>
        <Card.Text>
          Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the
          bulk of the card's content.
        </Card.Text>
        <Button variant='primary'>Go somewhere</Button>
      </Card.Body>
    </Card>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. for more optimizing you can use this option in Next.config.js:
   [image-optimization-nextjs][1]
   [1]: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/image-optimization#loader
2. you don't need to import images on your page. next/image by default recognize /public dir. src="/delta-logo.png"
3. and You can either use width and height properties in Image tag.

Answer (score 2):

You can either use `width` and `height` properties in `Image` like

```
<Image src={logo} alt='Picture of our Logo' width={500} height={500}/>
```

OR

Define a class for your image in your CSS file, and add that `className` to your `Image` tag like

```
<Image src={logo} alt='Picture of our Logo' className='yourClass'/>
```

Comment: I was unable to get it to work creating a class in my CSS file. Has things changed? I even tried className={styles.logo}. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the size of the image using the following approach

```
<div className="relative w-[50px] h-[50px] md:w-[100px] md:h-[100px]">
   <Image src="/images/myImage.png" alt="logo" fill />
</div>
```

Enclose the `<Image>` tag within a  element, apply the 'relative' positioning to the div, and adjust the image size using Tailwind CSS classes. Additionally, make sure to include the 'fill' property on the  tag.

Answer (score 0):

NextJS'  components added an option called "sizes", which main objective is to provide information about the sizes of the image in different breakpoints.

```js
import Image from 'next/image'

// ... Your code
 
export default function Page() {
  return (
    <div className="grid-element">
      <Image
        fill
        src="/example.png"
        sizes="(max-width: 768px) 100vw, (max-width: 1200px) 50vw, 33vw"
      />
    </div>
  )
}

// ...Your code
```

Additionally, you can install the sharp module that optimize images for production with `npm install sharp`.

Check more info in the [NextJS Docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/image#sizes).